# Query only get 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a mysql_query - YES, i know it's updated and i need to upgrade it to pdo or mysqli..

However, it only get one row from the database, where it needed to pull out 3 rows. It only take the first row it find.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM packages WHERE workerid = '$id' AND approved = '1'");
$packed = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $packed[] = $row;
return $packed;
}
```

Right now i just `print_r($packed);`, which only give me the first row of the table. Workerid and approved are checked on the other rows, and they should be able to get pulled out. I have a similar code in my functions, which work perfect, so i cant really see the error here.

Comment: Your return is in the `while` loop

Comment: You're overwriting `$packed` each time you loop.

Comment: Thank you, haven't seen that one :)!

Comment: For future readers of this question: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @JayBlanchard `$packed[] = ...` appends to the array, it doesn't overwrite it - it's like `array_push` without the function overhead and is better to use when appending a single value onto an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could try

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
array_push($packed, $row);
}

print_r($packed);

return $packed;
```

or

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $packed[] = $row;
   }

   print_r($packed);

   return $packed;
```

This should push each row return onto the end of the array. I am using print_r so that you can see if the array contains all the values you are looking for.

Comment: I've already found the solution, and that was the return inside the loop that needed to get moved.